# CrmSvcUtil.exe throwing a 401 unauthorized error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a crm 2011 instance running on a box that is joined to a domain.
I'm trying to run crmsvcutil from outside the domain using the following.

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /out:Xrm.cs /url:http://crm.mydomain.com/MSCRMDEV/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ /domain:MYDOMAIN  /u:mydomain\username /p:mypassword /namespace:Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext
```

This generates the following error

> CrmSvcUtil.exe Error: 0 : Exiting program with exit code 2 due to exception : System.InvalidOperationException: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://crm.mydomain.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/?wsdl'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataLocationRetriever.DownloadMetadata(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataRetriever.Retrieve(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataRetriever.Retrieve(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.ResolveNext(ResolveCallState resolveCallState)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.GetMetadata(MetadataRetriever retriever)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceMetadataUtility.RetrieveServiceEndpointMetadata(Type contractType, Uri serviceUri, Boolean checkForSecondary)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1..ctor(Uri serviceUri, Boolean checkForSecondary)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1..ctor(Uri serviceUri)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceConfiguration.AdjustServiceEndpoint(Uri serviceUri)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceConfiguration..ctor(Uri serviceUri)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration[TService](Uri serviceUri)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.SdkMetadataProviderService.CreateOrganizationServiceEndpoint()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.SdkMetadataProviderService.Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.IMetadataProviderService.LoadMetadata()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.CrmSvcUtil.Run()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.CrmSvcUtil.Main(String[] args)

The trace from Fiddler

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>   Cache-Control: private
>   Content-Length: 0
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
>   WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Mon, 06 Aug 2012 00:44:07 GMT
>   Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
>   No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present.
>   WWW-Authenticate Header is present: Negotiate
>   WWW-Authenticate Header is present: NTLM

The user/pass are that of a domain admin which is also a crm admin. What am I missing?
The interesting thing to note is that the URL in the error message does not contain the ORG name

'http://crm.mydomain.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc' <--- missing the org name here

from IIS logs I see a 401.5 which is "An ISAPI extension or CGI application denied the request":

2012-08-12 16:50:03 192.168.230.201 GET /MYORGNAME/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc wsdl+OnBeginRequest:08/12/2012-16:50:03.527+LogEntries:0+SqlCalls:0+SqlCallsMs:0+GC:1+OnEndRequest:16:50:03.528 80 - 192.168.230.201 - 401 5 0 3
2012-08-12 16:50:03 192.168.230.201 GET /XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc wsdl+OnBeginRequest:08/12/2012-16:50:03.538+LogEntries:0+SqlCalls:0+SqlCallsMs:0+GC:1+OnEndRequest:16:50:03.538 80 - 192.168.230.201 - 401 5 0 4

Comment: This is happening when running locally on the CRM box itself so does not seem like a cross domain issue

Comment: if you navigate to the endpoint as the user what happens?

Comment: navigation via browser woks fine. challenge/response when going cross domain anh integrated auth when in the domain

Comment: are you able to run svcutil from the machine in that case, just to rule out any cross domain wackyness.

Comment: Correction. I'm getting a challenge response locally (on the crm box) as well, so kerberos issue perhaps?  if I do an add service ref in VS(from the non domain box) I get a challenge response prompt ( twice) after which I can see the service and can download the wsdl to generate the proxy

Comment: Im not able to generate the proxy from the crm box either

Comment: o yeah of course, proxy != strongly type classes, erm...running out of ideas im afraid, are you able to use the Crm install account from the Crm server itself, as that should definetly have access.

Comment: I was able to get past the browser challenge/response (locally from the crm box), turns out I needed to add crm.mydomain.com to the  local intranet zone. But crmsvcutil still gives me a 401.  I have added the Fiddler trace to the question

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the fact that crmsvcutil is not using  the ORG name for downloading the metadata. Does anyone have an idea as to why?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily solve your problem by following these instructions : http://blog.thinketg.com/blog/ben-klopfer/strongly-typed-code-file-generation-with-crmsvcutilexe-for-crm-2011-ifd-configurations-code

Regards,

Kévin

Comment: Why is this needed. I have been able to use the crmscutil in an installation where crm was installed without a host name without having to provide a Metadata provider implementation just for generating a proxy. Moreover this is not an IFD